# cmd /c behaves differently on server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012, windows-command-prompt

Tried writing a batch file to shutdown my 2012 server, but ran into a weird issue. For example on 2008 a batch file like the following runs as expected:

```
cmd /c shutdown -s -t 0
```

On server 2012 when I click the batch file it continuously spawns cmd processes until I forcible close it. What gives?

Comment: It's 2012's way of saying "Use Powershell"

Comment: mmmk, but what is this? I tried googling this behavior, but didn't get anywhere. Is there a technet doc explaining this or something? What is this *called*- is it clear what I'm asking?

Comment: Also, kind of an obtuse way to handled this when they could have, I don't know, popped a message that says "Use Powershell".

Comment: @red888 I believe TheCleaner is being a bit facetious.  Your script works fine for me on Server 2012 R2.  Are you doing Run as Administrator on the batch file?  The Powershell equivalent is `Stop-Computer`.

Comment: Also, every time someone uses cmd/bat on Server 2012, I kick a puppy.  Keep it up and the neighbor kids are going to be distraught when their dog gets kicked to death.

Comment: Like @jscott said...I was being facetious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> when I click the batch file it continuously spawns cmd processes until I forcible close it.

Just out of curiosity, what did you name the script?  Did you happen to name it `shutdown.bat` or `shutdown.cmd` perhaps?

If so, the script is calling itself because of how Windows resolves the path for commands.  Use the full path to shutdown.exe, issue a CD command in your script, or rename your script.

Comment: god I feel dumb, I named it shutdown.bat. I think you figured it out, thanks.